# How to configure markdown-mode to render headings like org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, markdown-mode

Beloved org-mode can be configured so that different headings (aka, entry titles) display with different colors depending on their nesting level, and so that they only show the final markup character instead of the whole string of them.

Is it possible to configure emacs so markdown mode also renders like this?

I notice markdown-mode lets you fold to show only headings, but they are all rendered in the same color, and littered with # characters.

Comment: I think it is designed to work as you expect out of the box, but the author has made all of the heading levels the same face -- i.e., `:inherit markdown-header-face` :  https://github.com/defunkt/markdown-mode/blob/master/markdown-mode.el  So, consider changing a few faces to different `:foreground` colors and see if that makes a difference --  `markdown-header-face-1`; `markdown-header-face-2`; `markdown-header-face-3`

Comment: @Drew This is it. There is a customization subgroup that lets you tweak all the faces. Thanks! I'm still not sure how to suppress some of the # marks, but getting the colors right is the big one.

Comment: For the # marks, customize the `markdown-header-delimiter-face`.

Answer (score 4):

Markup hiding is now part of the [current development version](https://github.com/jrblevin/markdown-mode) of [Markdown mode](http://jblevins.org/projects/markdown-mode/).  Markup for headings, but also bold, italics, links, code, etc. can be hidden and toggled interactively using <kbd>C-c C-x C-m</kbd> (`M-x markdown-toggle-markup-hiding`).  I should note that this is slightly different than what you asked in your question: even the final hash mark is hidden.  You can set the default state by customizing `markdown-hide-markup`.

Indeed, as lawlist mentioned in a comment, to change the colors you can customize the specific heading level faces: `markdown-header-face-1` to `markdown-header-face-6`.  These all inherit from `markdown-header-face`, which is why the default colors are all the same.  Themes can certainly customize the colors to be different.

Also, variable height heading faces have been built in for a while now.  Set `markdown-header-scaling` to `t` to enable that.

Answer (score 3):

Colors and other attributes can be manually changed atleast:

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42673953/customize-appearance-of-emacs-markdown-mode?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa):

1. Click on a place where there is no text in the whole line.
2. `M-x customize-face`
3. `Customize face (default ‘all faces’): Customize face (default ‘all faces’):`  appears in the buffer. `RET`
4. find `markdown-header-face-1`, `markdown-header-face-2`, `markdown-header-face-3`, `markdown-header-face-4` ...
5. Click `markdown-header-face-1` --> `show all attributes' --> Change` foreground`to what you want and then click`State` and save for future sessions.
6. Same for other face levels.

**Instead, you can write this in the init file:**

```lisp
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(markdown-header-face-1 ((t (:inherit markdown-header-face :foreground "medium blue" :height 1.0))))
 '(markdown-header-face-2 ((t (:inherit markdown-header-face :foreground "medium blue" :height 1.0))))
 '(markdown-header-face-3 ((t (:inherit markdown-header-face :foreground "dark orange" :height 1.0))))
 '(markdown-header-face-4 ((t (:inherit markdown-header-face :foreground "dark cyan" :height 1.0)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

https://github.com/jrblevin/markdown-mode/issues/130

https://github.com/jrblevin/markdown-mode/issues/121#issuecomment-198461508

```
(custom-set-faces
 '(markdown-header-face ((t (:inherit font-lock-function-name-face :weight bold :family "variable-pitch"))))
 '(markdown-header-face-1 ((t (:inherit markdown-header-face :height 1.8))))
 '(markdown-header-face-2 ((t (:inherit markdown-header-face :height 1.4))))
 '(markdown-header-face-3 ((t (:inherit markdown-header-face :height 1.2)))))
```